# ListView, Change each row with Array of color codes in Android

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I'm trying to change the color of each row, I have 2 arrays. One has names of color, the other has color codes.

I have a ListView with Color names, the names are stored in an array of String.

```
String[] colourNames;
String[] colourCodes;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     colourNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray);
     colourCodes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listValues);

     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, colourNames);

    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    for(int i=0; i<colourCodes.length; i++)
        lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colourCodes[i]));
 }
```

In arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="listArray">
        <item>aliceblue</item>
        <item>antiquewhite</item>
        <item>aquamarine</item>
        <item>azure</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="listValues">
        <item>00f0f8ff</item>
        <item>00faebd7</item>
        <item>007fffd4</item>
        <item>00f0ffff</item>
 </string-array>
```

The app crashes at            `lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(colourCodes[i]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must write your own custom ArrayAdapter.

First write a color class:

**color.java:**

```
public class color {
    private String name;
    private String color;

    public color(String name, String color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }
}
```

Then List item layout:

**list_item_layout.xml**

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally write custom adapter:

**ColorListAdapter.java:**

```
public class ColorListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<color> mColorList;

public ColorListAdapter(Activity activity, List<color> mColorList) {
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mColorList = mColorList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mColorList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mColorList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView;

    // Get item_layout:
    rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, null);

    // Get TextView from item_layout:
    TextView textView =
            (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    // Get color and text from current position set TextView
    color myColor = mColorList.get(position);
    textView.setText(myColor.getName());
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(myColor.getColor()));
    return rowView;
  }
}
```

And these are **MainActivity.java** and **activity_main.xml**

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<color> colorList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Add color objects:
        colorList.add(new color("RED", "#FF0000"));
        colorList.add(new color("GREEN", "#00FF00"));
        colorList.add(new color("BLUE", "#0000FF"));
        colorList.add(new color("MY BEST", "#013583"));


        // Add list to your custom adapter
        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.liste);
        ColorListAdapter mAdapter = new ColorListAdapter(this, colorList);

        // Set Adapter
        myListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/liste"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
String[] colourNames;
String[] colourCodes;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     colourNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray);
     colourCodes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listValues);

     ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    ArrayAdapter aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, colourNames);

    lv.setAdapter(aa);

    for(int i=0; i<colourCodes.length; i++){
       View wantedView = lv.getChildAt(i);
       view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);  
      }
  }
```

Comment: lv.getChildAt(i); is returning null

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at this point `ListView` does not have any children. If you want to alter how children are displayed, you need create your own `Adapter` implementation and override `getView()`. You can simply subclass `ArrayAdapter` in this case and pass it your array of colors (or have it load the colors in the adapter, as I have done), then choose a color based on position.

Also, you might as well make your colors an [integer array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#IntegerArray).

```
<integer-array name="listValues">
    <item>0xfff0f8ff</item>
    <item>0xfffaebd7</item>
    <item>0xff7fffd4</item>
    <item>0xfff0ffff</item>
</integer-array>

public class ColorsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private int[] mColors;

    public ColorsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_listview,
                context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listArray));
        mColors = context.getResources().getIntegerArray(R.array.listValues);
    {

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int color = mColors[position % mColors.length]; // might as well be safe
        view.setBackgroundColor(color);
        return view;
    }
}
```

I also highly recommend watching this video on how ListView works: [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiU54zM1_rKAhUUImMKHV8dAeUQtwIIHTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&usg=AFQjCNF5_lMTBUGWJz4gD4HgimG5qv4KBQ&sig2=fr2tLoiIQfSuVhypg_54hw). Also, nowadays people are moving toward `RecyclerView` instead; you don't have to do that necessarily, but either way this video should help you understand how these components behave.